# Ace-editor: How to prevent some tags to be wrapped with P

Tags: javascript, html, editor, ckeditor, ace-editor

How i can config ace-editor to prevent wrapping for example anchor tag with p tag?
I have found similar solution only for cke editor: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Need-Help-CKEditor-is-deleting-my-xml-tags-and-adding-p-tags
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not give enough information to know what problem you see, but the most likely one is the following:

Ace doesn't modify the code you give it in any way, and it doesn't wrap tags with other tags.
However if you are inserting some text into html, and then telling ace to use it, it is easy to make a novice mistake of not escaping html properly.

You need to make sure to change all occurrences of `<` and `&` to `&lt;` and `&amp;` otherwise browser will interpret text as html, and you'll see all kinds of strange modifications.